# How can I draw colored shapes on gray Bitmap image?

Tags: .net, opencv, graphics, bitmap, emgucv

I have gray Bitmap image.

```
       Image<Gray, byte> cannyImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(pathImg);
       Bitmap drawImg = cannyImage.ToBitmap();
```

I want to draw on this image some shape :

```
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawImg);
    g.DrawLines(new Pen(Color.Purple), shapes[0].sample.pointsArray);
```

In last row of the code I get this error:

**A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.**

Any idea how can I draw colored shapes on gray Bitmap image?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: A Purple pixel, (RGB: 230, 230, 250 , can be stored in a byte only if some indexing table is used to store colors , ie image header has a table which defines the  256 colors which are permitted.i think  need Bgr when creating the image to be able to use colors on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to Bgr (RGB) and then give your code a try.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> cannyBgr = cannyImage.Convert<Bgr, Byte>();
Bitmap drawImg = cannyBgr.ToBitmap();
```